# Debugger exception notification error for reading txt files in DELPHI

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Im getting an error I haven't seen before.

Here's my code:

```
procedure TfrmPatientViewer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyArray : array [1..100] of string;
  iCount : Integer;
  Patients : TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(Patients, 'patients.txt');
  if FileExists('patients.txt') <> True
    then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Patients.txt does not exist, program shutting down');
        Application.Terminate;
      end;
  iCount := 1;
  while not Eof(Patients) do // <-- HERE'S THE ERROR
    begin
      Readln (Patients, MyArray[iCount]);
      redtOut.Lines.Add(MyArray[iCount]);
      inc(iCount);
    end;
end;
```

The error says: `Project  Phase3P.exe has raised an exception class ElnOutError with message 'I/O error 104'. Proccess stopped`.

Why is it doing this and what can I do to make it work properly? I have searched around an can only find stuff on different I/O errors, but not this `104` one.

Comment: Just a hint, you dont have to check `fileexists <> true` since the function returns a boolean you can simply put `if not FileExists('patients.txt') then ...` Im also wondering if you're checking at the right point. I would think you should check it before the AssignFile although that's not related to your problem.

Comment: @TeunPronk Noted. Never really thought of that before. Thank you

Comment: No problem, not sure what part you mean but I ran a quick test and you will get an `EInOutError` when the file doesn't exist. Ill put a suggested solution to that lower.

Comment: I found this page, useful for errors http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.EInOutError

Comment: @Teun, `AssignFile` performs no actual I/O. All it does is set fields in the `TextFile` record so that a subsequent file-opening function knows what to do. (But `Eof` is not a file-opening function.) Thus, checking before or after `FileExists` makes no difference.

Comment: @RobKennedy I still got an error while using AssignFile on an non-existing file. So checking `FileExists` should be done before assigning right?

Comment: @Teun, do you mean you got an error *from* `AssignFile`? That shouldn't happen. `AssignFile` is used for creating new files as well as for opening existing files. Or do you mean you still got an error from Link's code? That's to be expected because Link's code is wrong; it neglects to open the file in any way. That's why it generates error 104: "*File not open* for input" (emphasis mine). Or do you mean an error in *your* code? You should always expect an error when calling `Reset` when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @RobKennedy ah youre right, the error occured on a different line. My bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found my error after proof reading for the 4th time xD

I didn't put the `reset(patients)` after assigning the text file.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as 'the' answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggested edit for error.

```
procedure TfrmPatientViewer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyArray : array [1..100] of string;
  iCount : Integer;
  Patients : TextFile;
begin
  try
    AssignFile(Patients,'patients2.txt');
    reset(Patients);
    iCount := 1;
    while not Eof(Patients) do // <-- HERE'S THE ERROR
      begin
        Readln (Patients, MyArray[iCount]);
        redtOut.Lines.Add(MyArray[iCount]);
        inc(iCount);
      end;
  except
    on E: EInOutError do
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Patients.txt does not exist, program shutting down');
      Application.Terminate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This way you don't have to check the FileExists and it will raise your exception if its not found.
The one downside is that only the exception of `EInOutError` will raise the message.